# Function to combine Python3 generator and instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I wrote a generator function that I instantiate then call over and over again, each time this increments the number.

```
def pagecnt():
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1

pg = pagecnt()
print(next(pg))
print(next(pg))
print(next(pg))
```

This prints 1, 2 and then 3. Is there some way to combine the generator and instantiation into a new function so that I can just call

```
print(newfunc())
print(newfunc())
print(newfunc())
```

to get 1, 2 and 3?

EDIT: I don't just want to call it only 3 times. It's used to generate page number. So I don't know in advance how many times I am going to call it. And between each call, there's lots of code to calculate stuff and generate graphs.

Comment: `def newfunc(): return next(pg)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a simple Counter class with `__call__()` defined:

```
class Counter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    def __call__(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count

c = Counter()
print(c())
print(c())
print(c())
```

**prints:**

```
1
2
3
```

You could also capture the iterator in a closure and return a lambda function:

```
from itertools import count

def Counter():
    it = count(1)
    return lambda: next(it)

c = Counter()
print(c())
print(c())
print(c())
```

prints the same as above. In both cases it would be easy to pass in a start value if you wanted to begin somewhere other than 0.

Edit:

This is the same as using count but with your custom generator:

```
def Counter():
    def pagecnt():
        n = 1
        while True:
            yield n
            n += 1
    it = pagecnt()
    return lambda: next(it)

c = Counter()
print(c())
print(c())
print(c())
```

Comment: I was really hoping to do it with a generator. Can I substitute the itertools with my own generator?

Comment: @Alpha8 -- you can directly substitute your `pagecnt` function for `count` if you'd rather use that.

Comment: @MarkMeyer You are instantiating with c = Counter(). Can we combine it into the Counter() code?

Comment: @Alpha8, not really. You need some way to maintain state which means the function needs to create something and return a callable object. If it's all inside the function each call will start over.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a function which instantiates your generator and calls `next` n times

```
def combine_func(n):
    pg = pagecnt()
    for _ in range(n):
        print(next(pg))
```

Or we can define a wrapper function which takes in the generator instance, and returns a function which we can call to get the next element

```
def combine_func(pg):

    def next_elem():
        return next(pg)

    return next_elem

pg = pagecnt()
cf = combine_func(pg)
print(cf())
print(cf())
print(cf())
```